# Can I use branches to hold different but related projects?

Tags: git

I have 5 projects that inherit some code from a base project. I'm wondering if I can put them all in only one repository by creating one branch for each project within that repository. Not sure if branch can be used like that.

What's the best approach?

Comment: "can" and "should" are very different things :)

Comment: hehe, let's say if I "should"

Comment: can - yes. should - no. What is your thinking for setting things up like that?

Comment: just to have these projects in 1 repo. But if i keep them in same branch, if i need to revert some commit I would lose the commit for other projects.

Comment: Definitely you can do this... However, when the new guy joins the team and decides to try his hand at a merge, without fully understanding your odd configuration, much "fun" will be had... Definition 2375834 for "foot gun"...

Comment: Understand the attraction, but a repo is _incredibly_ lightweight.  Here's how you create the minimum functional repo: `mkdir -p .git/{refs,objects}; echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD; git config core.repositoryformatversion=0`.  Making a new repo is actually far more often than not the right way to make a new branch even within a project, you can push work around much more conveniently when you've got a bunch of cooperating repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches are used to create seperate development "lines" for the same product - so every branch usually shares most of the code with other branches or the master branch respectively. Git is used to quickly switch between these and changes what files in what version are in your local working directory.

A common use case is to create a new branch to work on a new feature or to fix a bug. You start off with the current (or a recent) state of your code, then do changes and see if it works. You can safely do this in your WIP branch while keeping the master branch in a stable state, and revert to older revisions any time you mess something up. Once your done and happy with your new code (and tested it extensively), you can merge that brach into the master.

There's only one branch checkout at a time, which means you can only open and edit the files of that branch. If you want to change the files of another branch, you'll need to stash your changes and checkout that other branch. If you used multiple branches for different, but related projects, it would mean that you can never access all of your code at the same time - which makes no sense.

If you want to organize sub-projects in your repository, use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). If your entire code base is rather small, just organize everything in a clean folder hierarchy, for example:

```
Repo
|__ Subproject 1
|   |__ lib
|   |__ exports
|   |__ src
|
|__ Subproject 2
|   |__ lib
|   |__ themes
|   |__ src
|   |__ utils
|
|__ ...
```

Comment: I updated. Take a look if that changes your answer pls.

Comment: My main point remains, you can't check out multiple branches at once and thus not access all of your projects simultaneously. And if there are interdependencies, it's an even worse idea, 'cause you basically need to merge / rebase whenever you change the shared code bits. I see no benefit in using branches, the few bytes you might save on your hdd aren't worth it. Use submodules if you have a lot of code to organize, with the shared stuff at the root, and the subprojects as submodules. Or use multiple repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it's usually not better than having multiple repositories – the only good reason to do it is if there are external pressures preventing you from creating more repositories.

That said, the thing to use is `git checkout --orphan NEWBRANCH`. To use this to create a branch with entirely unrelated files (as you seem to want to), you should get rid of all previously tracked files after executing the first command but before doing anything else, e.g. using `git rm -rf .` from the top level as suggested in the manpage.

I strongly recommend checking that you don't have any uncommitted changes worth keeping before you do any of this.